# WAMP error: forbidden, You don't have permission to access /url/ on this server

Tags: wamp, wampserver

> You don't have permission to access /DiveBay/'.http://localhost/DiveBay/placefeedback2.php.' on this server.

I just got thrown this error by my wampserver project. I've made about 20+ php scripts/pages for it and have never seen this before. I'm trying to access the page through a form action on another page.

Why is this occurring? Would someone please tell me what to do? The only thing that seems obvious to me is that the URL may be wrong and should just be divebay/placefeedback2.php.

I haven't changed the permissions of the file or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but it may always help:

http://aboukone.com/2011/04/25/wamp-apache-error-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\ ,right click on "wamp" folder,click the "security" tab ,click on "edit".In the "Group or user names" textbox/section,pick "your login name" and check "Full control".Click ok when you through. 
Go to C:\wamp,right click on "www" and do the same as above.

OR

Type in "127.0.0.1" without the quote in your browser

Remember to "Mark/Tick" if this solve your problem.